# Youtube Api, cannot upload videos ruby

Tags: ruby, video, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-client

I have been looking for a solution to upload my videos on youtube automatically. So naturally i went and looked up the Youtube api (ruby). The sample for the upload is completely wrong, it require files that do not exist, call functions with the wrong numbers of arguments and even one that does not exist. So i moved on and tried the gem called "yt" but you cannot upload files from your computer you need to pass the url of a video which is not what i want. There are my questions :

Is there any version of the gooogle-client-api where the upload sample work or am i missing something about it?

Is there any alternative to upload videos automatically on youtube ?

Comment: I kind of doubt that the youtube examples are really wrong. It's more likely that you're not using the correct gem version. Can you verify that you're using `gem 'google-api-client', '>0.7'` like in the example? Maybe it would be easier to close their examples repo [here](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples) to make sure all the correct files are in place.

Comment: They are wrong, just look at the requires, there are the sources
https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/tree/master/lib/google

I'm using the last version of this gem (11.1) so i guess they haven't "updated" the samples yet (3 years). I'm curious in which version did they work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [yt gem](https://github.com/Fullscreen/yt)? It's actively maintained and well-documented.

There's examples on uploading a video [here](http://fullscreen.github.io/yt/accounts.html).

Example of uploading a local video using its path:

```
account.upload_video "v.mp4", privacy_status: "private" # => #<Yt::Video …>
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it seems like you cannot upload files directly you have to give an url :x Maybe i'm using it wrong ?

Comment: The documentation says you can either use a path or a url, see [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yt/Yt%2FModels%2FAccount:upload_video).

Comment: Ok so i just tried once again and i guess it's a bug. When trying to upload from my computer(only) the video stays at "0% imported" as you can see here : https://gyazo.com/bbb10d30c17fa1a10d1759d6e99d01d6 

And my ruby program just never stops. Have you any idea from where it might come ?

Comment: I guess either a firewall or slow internet could do that? Try using a network monitor and see if anything is actually being uploaded.

Comment: I don't think that's the case since i have been able to upload a video from the net, a rails cast one just to try, and i have a pretty decent upload (14MO)

Comment: Are you sure nothing is preventing the Ruby process from uploading?

Comment: If that's the case i have no idea what it might be. But i might have a clue of where the problem might come from. I had a lot of mp4 (1 to 2 min) and i merged them to create video from 8 to 10 min long. Doing this i had to modify them so they could merge together. The funny thing is that for example i cannot read them from vlc, it crashes(it works on windows players). But when i upload them manually everything's works. I'm guessing it's because youtube re-encode the video. Do you think that when receiving a file from the ap,i youtube scan it and if there are errors just dismiss it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141765/discussion-between-omar-bahareth-and-tylo).